# Is there any way to click the "Sign In" link on github page using javascript for testcafe?

Tags: javascript, github, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to click the "Sign In" on the GitHub page for testcafe using javascript. From inspecting part I found that "Sign in" part has a class name. So I was trying to use "Selector" to select that particular class. But it is giving me this error. "The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

```
   Selector('HeaderMenu-link no-underline mr-3').withText('Sign&nbsp;in')
```

Comment: Hello Maeesha , i would try it without the .  , or with ('btn-block') only

Comment: sorry, it was Selector('HeaderMenu-link no-underline mr-3').withText('Sign&nbsp;in'). But still did not work

Comment: Selector('.mr-3').withText('Sign&nbsp;in').

Comment: it is still showing the same error.

Comment: May not be possible to do it so, maybe the button does not exist in the DOM?

Comment: Then how can I click "sign in" on github page using javascript for testcafe?

Comment: Looks like GitHub has some 'special' dynamic coding that exists.  Alternative solution would just to bypass that page completely.  Unless you absolutely need to test/click on that button, I would just go directly to the login URL:  http://github.com/login

Comment: if I go directly to the login page still I have to click the sign In button in that page. I am also unable to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check the following test, it successfully clicks the "Sign In" button for me:

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import { pick } from 'lodash';

fixture `GitHub`.page `github.com`;

test(`Click Sign In`, async t => {
    await t.maximizeWindow();
    await t.click(Selector('a.HeaderMenu-link').withText('Sign\u00a0in'));
    await t.wait(3000);
});
```

The `&nbsp;` is a HTML control sequence that can be used only in HTML documents. In plain JS strings it's represented by the `\u00a0` character. I agree that it is quite obscure. We will try to simplify handling of such characters in the context of issue [#3937](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3937)